# Unable to access CodeIgniter methods inside jQuery loaded PHP

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using the jQuery .load() method to load a php file into a div inside my view. This is because on some actions on the page, I don't want the whole page to refresh, instead I just want a single div to change its contents.

```
//view file

function loadCallback(a) 
{
  $('#div').load("/inner.php", {json: JSON.stringify(a)});
}

function load() 
{
  $.post('/controller/method', {}, loadCallback, 'json');
}
```

The loaded php file does some server side processing. Everything was working fine till I needed to localize this file, for which I was using the CodeIgniter language helper throughout my code. The lang() method does not work inside this dynamically loaded PHP, although it works everywhere else. It seems this PHP doesn't have the context of CodeIgniter's framework. Even getinstance() doesn't work from inside the file. I am guessing there is no workaround for this on the dynamically loaded PHP side.

```
//inner view (inner.php)
$stringValue = lang('key');

//PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function lang() in inner.php
```

Since I am loading this PHP from a view file via javascript, I am unable to use the PHP lang functions there too, and am having to send these static localized strings all the way from controller using the callback variable, which I find quite hacky.

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: put your inner.php logic inside a code igniter controller, and have the controller echo out your view file

Comment: are you autoloading the helper ? or are you running this `$this->load->helper('language');`  before calling `lang`?

Comment: inner.php is a view file?

Comment: @Vinod VT: inner.php is a view file. The controller is passing the data to the view via the callback.

Comment: @anurupr: autoloading the helper.

Comment: @Rooster: inner.php is a view file, it just takes in the data from the controller via the main view and spits outs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like my comment, put your inner.php logic inside a code igniter controller, and have the controller echo out your view file, right now you're just hitting a page called your_domain.com/inner.php, not a view file called inner.php

so instead of:

```
function loadCallback(a) 
{
  $('#div').load("/inner.php", {json: JSON.stringify(a)});
}
```

do something like:

```
function loadCallback(a) 
{
  $('#div').load("/controller/ajax_method", {json: JSON.stringify(a)});
}
```

and then inside your controller:

```
function ajax_method(){
    //some logic....
    $this->load->view('inner', $data);
}
```

you might need to json_encode the view in your ajax_method function since you seem to want to do that, in which case sometihng like:

```
function ajax_method(){
    //some logic
    $json['json'] = $this->load->view('inner', $data, true)
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Won't the this->load->view() call inside the controller append the view to the html of the page also?

Comment: no, because you're inserting what it returns to the div element with the id="div1"  ...ie: $('#div').load(....

Comment: Ohkie, let me try this and see if it works out. I can see how the localization problem will get solved, but I am a bit apprehensive of the code flow.

Comment: I think that in the controller you missed the $data: `$this->load->view('inner', $data, true);`

Comment: @Chococroc ahh nice catch, been a while since I was using CI routinely.  Edited.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: @Rooster: It worked pretty well, thanks! And yes, I had to add the extra data param, but figured it out, thanks Chocoroc. I have stopped using json encoding now, since don't see any point for it.